# Can I request for vote up?

Tags: discussion

I am thinking about if someone's question is good (not perfect or very smart) and some people are viewing and commenting. But no one is giving an answer and instead votes down.

So it means the question is technical and there is chance of a solution. So in this case a user can request of a viewer that if you think the question is a good technical one then kindly vote it up so that this question can get more attention.

I am sorry if it is bad idea. Thank you.

Comment: Begging for an upvote will usually get you more downvotes

Comment: @AlonEitan yes it can also be happen

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking. But the OP is more than welcome to ask for clarifications for the downvotes (in the comments section) - Usually they will get a reply with suggestions of how to improve their post

Comment: I highly doubt that a good question would get downvotes.

Comment: _So in this case a user can request to viewer that if you think question is good technical then kind vote it up_ This is what the upvote button is for anyway, but it's not up to other users to decide on whether or not it's a good question, that's down to each individual user to decide themselves, When you get enough rep you'll be able to see how many people have downvoted and upvoted a question and even good questions with hundreds of upvotes have a few downvotes.

Comment: "But no one is giving answer and vote down. So its means question is technical and there is chance of solution." What kind of nonsensical logic is that? How does a question not getting answers correlate with there being a chance of a solution?

Comment: @BoltClock My best guess is that the OP means that because it's *only* getting down votes as opposed to close votes that means it's still an on topic question. "Chance of solution" meaning "on-topic and thus not blocked from being answered".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> some people are viewing and commenting [. . .] So its means question is technical and there is chance of solution

This is an invalid conclusion. If people are looking at the question but commenting instead of answering, it means the question is poor.

One common problem is that the question lacks sufficient information to make it possible to answer, forcing people to use the comments to ask for clarification. Incomplete questions are not good questions, and therefore do not deserve upvotes.

Another common problem is that the question is *too broad*, so people are leaving comments either to (A) help the asker narrow down the question to make it answerable in our format, or (B) be nice and give the asker a hint anyway, even though the question is ultimately doomed (and will be closed). Either way, such questions are not good questions, and do not deserve upvotes.

(Arguably, incomplete questions and those that are too broad *do* deserve downvotes, but often people are too nice and won't downvote questions like this, especially if they seem like earnest attempts.)

> I am thinking about if [. . .] a user can request to viewer that if you think question is good technical then kind vote it up that this question can get more attention.

I'm not sure how you're proposing that such a "request" would be made, but no matter how you spin it (a new "feature", or a whiny comment), this is a bad idea.

Begging for votes does not end well. Often, it backfires and you get downvotes instead. The rest of the time, people just ignore you.

It is also unbecoming. Users with voting privileges know how to use the vote arrows. If they thought the question merited an upvote, then they would have given you one. Unless they are out of votes for the day, in which case, begging wouldn't help, either.

And if begging *did* work, it would be an abuse of the voting system. Votes on Stack Overflow are used to rate content. If the content is useful and interesting to others, then it should be upvoted. Otherwise, it should not be upvoted. Pretty simple, and in practice, it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your knowledgeable answer +1

Comment: "Votes on Stack Overflow are used to rate content.": Then people should not downvote because someone begged for upvotes in the comments. Or comments are considered as part of the question's content?

Comment: They *shouldn't*, @bli, but they do. (Also, for what it's worth, having to beg for upvotes is a pretty good heuristic that the question is low-quality.)